# Open source threadpool lib

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss, weblogic-10.x

I was looking for open source thread pool lib which I can use to schedule the jobs and once that individual job is done I want some notification in the thread so that I can finish the rest of the task. Do you guys know any open source lib that is doing similar kind of work. I might be using this lib in multiple diff server.

Basic overview of my task is I have list of items. Each items needs to be submitted to other system throgh JMS/Webservice and then wait for response for each items being processed and do the rest of the task.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about j.u.c.[ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)? Properly wrapped and coupled with judicious use of [Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) it should meet your stated specs.  If you have specific "block this thread until the following task set completes" behavior, you may also make use of a [CompletionService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html).

As another answerer pointed out, you could also jump all the way to using [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), if you really need a fully-fleshed-out task scheduling service.  It sounds like that's overkill for your problem, but you didn't give specifics.  If this is the path you take, there's a [lot of good Q+A on Quartz Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler) here at SO.

Comment: My answer points you to TPE because it's not clear from your question whether you really need a robust task scheduling apparatus -- it sounds like you have some web service that spins off independent tasks from an initial task, and then wants to wait for their completion.  If you really need to *schedule* tasks, QuartzScheduler (see @harschware's answer) is the right solution.

Comment: thanks andersoj, after doing some initial proptotyping I think quartz fits to our need and in future we might also need cron jobs. So thank you very much for this information.

Answer (score 1):

Check out ScheduledExecutors, run beepForAnHour once after 10 seconds, then every 10 seconds thereafter:

```
 import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
       Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void beepForAnHour() {
        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
                public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
            };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
            }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
    }
 }
```

From:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) to me