# Java Threading - Alternative to spawning a huge amount of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server, simulation

I'm currently creating a simulation program to simulate clients moving around the map of a massively multiplayer online game. I have to have a grid to represent the map, which holds Client objects. These Clients must move around the grid randomly, each communicating with a Server object.

At the moment I start a new Thread for each Client, and it calls a method in its' server with a random direction of movement each second.

This works fine until I start adding a huge number of clients (~5000), where the program crashes and I get a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread" exception.

Is there an alternative way to deal with such a large amount of clients without them each being a separate thread?

Thanks, Dan

Comment: have you considered may be use a thread poor lib, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148561/open-source-threadpool-lib

Comment: There are lots of approaches.  Which one is likely to be best depends on what your goals are.  And also if the server is a remote machine you're talking to over the network or a local process.

Answer (score 4):

Why on earth are you giving each client its own thread? Simply have one thread do the following:

```
for (;;) {
    for (Client c : clients) {
        c.update();
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

That has the advantage that fairness is guaranteed (all clients get updated, even if the system is overloaded), and the server need not be thread-safe. Moreover, a for-loop is far more efficient than switching threads, will consume less memory (each thread has a stack allocated).

Comment: Assuming the scenario is a load test, doing them all sequentially isn't much of a test!

Comment: Is the scenario a load test? That is, is the network simulated or a real one used? The question says the clients are held in a collection, therefore in a single VM. Also, the question says methods are invoked on the server *object*, which leads me to be believe to actual servers are involved.

Comment: I agree with this answer, this is a classic example of overkill use of threading. If you want the clients to run randomly, pick a random number and update that client.

Comment: A shortcoming of the question, not of your answer :) +1

Comment: Guys, thanks your your comments. The network is indeed simulated and run in a single VM, but the simulated environment contains tens of servers as well as the many clients. I shall adopt the sequential method and see if my test results are workable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the actor concurrency model for that? Akka provides a mature library-based actor implementation for that. It allows you to create huge amount of objects that can communicate with each other using message passing. It is backed by a threadpool.

http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/java/untyped-actors.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of off the top of my head.

### 1 - Have each thread contain a collection of clients.

Instead of only 1 client per thread.  Try having a collection of X clients per thread.  Then loop through the clients moving each one.

### 2 - Truely distribute your clients

Use a JMeter or other distributed testing suite to spread threads across multiple computers.